# How to calculate difference between two values in different rows based on dates in same table

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle table structured like this:

```
Serial Some_value  Date(Date Field type)

1      100         4-10-2019 8:00

1      106         4-17-2019 7:00

2      100         4-10-2019 8:00

2      101         4-17-2019 6:33

3      100         4-10-2019 9:00

3      110         4-17-2019 6:00
```

I would like to have a query that returns serial numbers that have a difference greater than 5 between present reading and 7 days back. The output from the example table above would be like this:

```
Serial Difference

1      6

3      10
```

I currently have this SQL to get the present value and the value seven days back but I am struggling with piecing this all together.

```sql
  (select quantity from Parts where date > sysdate-1) -
  (select quantity from Parts where to_char(sysdate-7,'DDD') = 
   to_char(date,'DDD') and 
   to_char(sysdate-7,'YYYY') = to_char(date,'YYYY') and
   to_char(sysdate-7,'MM') = to_char(date,'MM'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
select * 
  from (
    select serial, 
           min(case when trunc(date_) = trunc(sysdate) then quantity end) 
         - min(case when trunc(date_) = trunc(sysdate - 7) then quantity end) diff
      from parts 
      where trunc(date_) in (trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate-7))
      group by serial)
  where diff > 5
```

or use `having` clause if you don't want subquery.

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=80bbed4cee779f49bd7957318aa896c0)</sup>**

Comment: This appears to be what I need. The query took around 25 seconds but there are over 30 million rows in this table.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using the `LAG` function here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Serial, Some_value, "Date",
        LAG(Some_value, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY "Date") Some_value_lag
    FROM Parts
)

SELECT
    Serial,
    "Date",
    ABS(Some_value - Some_value_lag) AS difference
FROM cte
WHERE
    ABS(Some_value - Some_value_lag) > 5
ORDER BY
    Serial,
    "Date";
```

[image]

### Demo

The CTE above first generates the lag of the `Some_value` column by date, within each group of serial records.  Then, we query to include only records for which the absolute difference between some values exceeds 5.  Note that the earliest record in each serial group would automatically not be included in the result set, because the `LAG` would return `NULL` in that case.  I went ahead and included the date in the output, because it makes it easier to read.

Comment: I tested this query and it seems to run faster than the subquery below but I need to compare today's value against the value seven days ago.